# Postfix user issue - One user receives mail, the other one not

Tags: postfix, dovecot, users

I just installed Dovecot and Postfix on my CentOS server.

Now, with that, I created 2 local users that will each have a mail account.

I did the following:

```
useradd dexter

mkdir /home/dexter/Maildir
chown mark:mark /home/dexter/Maildir
chmod -R 700 /home/dexter/Maildir
```

and for the second user:

```
useradd info

mkdir /home/info/Maildir
chown mark:mark /home/info/Maildir
chmod -R 700 /home/info/Maildir
```

**ISSUE:**
I can send mail to the 'dexter' user, and the emails land into his /Maildir/new or /Maildir/cur folder, **but** the other user - info, does not receive any mails sent to him. All his folders (Maildir/new and Maildir/cur) are empty.

Why is that?

Thanks

---

EDIT: /var/logs/maillog entries - I sent the same email to both users:

```
to=<dexter@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.35, delays=0.18/0.01/0/0.17, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)

to=<root@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<info@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.41, delays=0.18/0.01/0/0.22, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir
```

I replaced my actual domain name with 'mydomain.com'

Comment: what in the maillog /var/log/maillog ?

Comment: I will post the last few lines to my answer - Lines it the maillog i think might be relevant

Comment: All mails has been delivered to the maildir. For user info mail was forwarded to the root maildir, maybe you are using some aliases (/etc/aliases)

Comment: yeah, was just an alias issue. Fixed it in the /etc/aliases file.thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
to=<root@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<info@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.41, delays=0.18/0.01/0/0.22, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir
```

It seams your email has been forwarded to the `root` user mailbox. Check in his emails, you should see the email you originally sent.

- Edit `/etc/aliases` and remove the line which causes the forwarding to root ;
- Run `newaliases`.

I hope it should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Fox. I did do the change (see my updated answer) and I also ran the 'newaliases' command, but info is still not getting mail. I also restarted postfix, but nothing

Comment: # postmap -q root hash:/etc/aliases ?

Comment: OK Cool. I managed to get it to work. There were a couple of default redirects and info was one of them. info routed to 'postmaster' by default, so I just changed it to 'info'.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Your welcome! Actually, when you change a postfix setting, you never need to restart it, except if you change the **inet_interfaces** parameter. For other parameters, running `postfix reload` should suffice. For the special case of the `/etc/aliases`, a `newaliases` or `postaliases` is enough. Finally, for all other "map" files, you can just use `postmap /etc/postfix/mymap`.